# C# .net - Images fits differently on win7 than win8

Tags: c#, .net, image

I recently got myself a new laptop with Win8 OS, and started developing on this instead of my old with Win7.

I noticed recently that images fits differently on Windows 7 than it does on Windows 8 for some reason. You can see it in the picture below:

[image]
(The below image got pixely when I made it bigger due to screenshot taken by someone else)

But you can clearly see that the images doesn't fit on Windows 7.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You probably have a fixed DPI set.

Comment: You probably have a different DPI setting.

Comment: We think it's the DPI setting.  :-)

Comment: @LarsTech
So how would one go about fixing the issue?
The users are mostly Win7 users, but I don't want to use my old laptop just to develop when I got a new one or just this reason..

Comment: RIP Winforms. Long life to WPF

Comment: With out changing your code, just try setting your DPI to smaller in windows settings and see if that fixes. If it does, then you will probably have to rebuild in windows 8.

Comment: @Casper.BL I cant tell if your being sarcastic ;-)

Comment: @Anon No I'm serious, hehe, sorry! 
This actually solved my problem. A bit of a hassle to resize everything again, but the final product will be worth it hopefully :)